# Excel - Get uniques from a column after filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my source data, I have one column with companies, and one with products. My goal is to, using the company name, populate a list of the unique products for that client.

[image: Example Image from the workbook]

In the image, there are columns **A** (Companies) and **B** (Products). There are multiple company names repeated in column A, and multiple product names in column B. My goal would be to enter a company name in 1 cell and then in another series of cells, get a list of the unique values which that company has.

For my use-case, my list will never have different companies which share a product name. I also will have a maximum of 6 unique projects for each company.

I have found some references for generating unique lists, but I have been unable to work out how to limit their results by company name.

[Link to the partial solution](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list)

I am on the current version of Excel, if that has any impact. I had considered some non-formula solutions to this problem, but with my use case I will be duplicating sheets and a formula, if possible, would be the best fit for that. I appreciate any help/insight you can share. Thank you.

Comment: The most easiest I would like to suggest is,, Advance Filter on Company and select `Unique Records` option.

Comment: `RemoveDuplicates` on the original or copied table, then select from the Company filter.

Answer (score 0):

Since

> list will never have different companies which share a product name

Thus, please 'clean' the list by removing duplicates (there is duplicates in you example).
For this solution, I'm using the above cited condition with the duplicates removed list. Also assuming that the list is located in column A&B, the (entered) company name is in E1, and the 1st result is located at E3.

put this in E3 :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1,A:A,0)),"")
```

then this in E4, then drag downward :

```
=IF(E3="","",IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E3,B:B,0)+1)=$E$1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E3,B:B,0)+1),""))
```

Hope it helps. Do ask if there is difficulties with any part of the formula. ( :